# bitrix:catalog.store.amount считает остаток торгового предложения, не товара

Tags: битрикс

Почему до вызова компонента и после вызова компонента `bitrix:catalog.store.amount`:

```html
<?$APPLICATION->IncludeComponent("bitrix:catalog.store.amount", "store_amount", array(
   "ELEMENT_ID" => $ElementID,
   "STORE_PATH" => $arParams['STORE_PATH'],
   "CACHE_TYPE" => "A",
   "CACHE_TIME" => "36000",
   "MAIN_TITLE" => $arParams['MAIN_TITLE'],
   "USE_MIN_AMOUNT" =>  $arParams['USE_MIN_AMOUNT'],
   "MIN_AMOUNT" => $arParams['MIN_AMOUNT'],
   "STORES" => $arParams['STORES'],
   "SHOW_EMPTY_STORE" => $arParams['SHOW_EMPTY_STORE'],
   "SHOW_GENERAL_STORE_INFORMATION" => $arParams['SHOW_GENERAL_STORE_INFORMATION'],
   "USER_FIELDS" => $arParams['USER_FIELDS'],
   "FIELDS" => $arParams['FIELDS']
  ),
  $component,
  array("HIDE_ICONS" => "Y")
 );?>
```

`$ElementId=5;` (в таблице `b_catalog_store_product` ничего нет).
Однако, в шаблоне компонента `bitrix:catalog.store.amount`,  если прописать `echo $arParams["ELEMENT_ID"];` , то выводятся тп id=65`; и кол-во торгового предложения, не товара (Если прописать`print_r($arResult["STORES"])`, то выведет` [0] => Array ( [ID] => 0 [AMOUNT] => 105 `). 
И выводит "общий остаток товара 100". (если торговое предложение, то остаток должен быть =105)

Почему , не знаю....

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галочка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У Вас в компоненте `bitrix:catalog` установлен параметр «Показывать общую информацию по складам». Снимите с него галочку и посмотрите.
Если вывести `$arResult`, то увидим следующую картину:

```
Array
(
    [IS_SKU] => 1
    [STORES] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [ID] => 1
                    [URL] => /store/1
                    [TITLE] => Склад
                    [PHONE] => 
                    [SCHEDULE] => 
                    [IMAGE_ID] => 
                    [EMAIL] => 
                    [COORDINATES] => 
                    [DESCRIPTION] => 
                    [AMOUNT] => 105
                    [REAL_AMOUNT] => 105
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [ID] => 2
                    [URL] => /store/2
                    [TITLE] => Склад2
                    [PHONE] => 
                    [SCHEDULE] => 
                    [IMAGE_ID] => 
                    [EMAIL] => 
                    [COORDINATES] => 
                    [DESCRIPTION] => 
                    [AMOUNT] => 20
                    [REAL_AMOUNT] => 20
                )

        )
    [JS] => Array
        (
            [SKU] => Array
                (
                    [156] => Array
                        (
                            [1] => 100
                            [2] => 50
                        )
                    [155] => Array
                        (
                            [1] => 100
                            [2] => 40
                        )
                    [154] => Array
                        (
                            [1] => 100
                            [2] => 30
                        )

                    [153] => Array
                        (
                            [1] => 100
                            [2] => 10
                        )

                    [152] => Array
                        (
                            [1] => 105
                            [2] => 20
                        )
                )
        )
)
```

Тут в массиве `[STORES]` находятся количество одного из ТП, в моём случае последнего, но при заходе на страницу активное ТП другое и выводится его количество. Если поискть, то найдётся нужное ТП и у него будет правильное количество. Компонент работает корректно, но обовляет данные через JS